# Conditionals in POSIX standards

Tags: shell, if-statement, posix

In these days I spent a lot of time reading various articles and guides about scripting (most of all in Bash). One of the first things that came up was that the best thing to do was sticking to POSIX, for portability.

Anyway, I couldn't get the standard way to make a conditional statement straight... I would like to ignore `test` in this post and discuss `[` and `[[` instead.

I found that `[` is a bit dated, but every shell supports it (older as alias of `/bin/test/`, "newer" as part of the shell themselves).

On the other hand, almost every tutorial I found use `[[`, and, when asked, the reason is something like "Bash is default in most of Linux distributions, so it's like a standard".

There are, of course, a lot of differences between them and personally I found `[[` easier to use.

What is the standard way to make a conditional statement? And if a standard way isn't defined: What is the best way? I have to achieve portability, not readability or easiness...

What is the position on "Bash is a de facto standard" and is it really safe to use it as a standard rather than only POSIX rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))-specific

```sh
[[ .. ]]
```

## [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) = `sh`, like [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash)

```sh
[ .. ]
```

As you also asked for personal opinion, mine is: If there is no reason to use the Bash-specific way, always try to adhere to POSIX standards.

---

### Two examples

**Comparing strings**

in Bash

```sh
[[ "$a" == "$b" ]]
```

in a POSIX shell

```sh
[ "$a" = "$b" ]
```

**While loop condition**

in Bash

```sh
while [[ "$i" > 0 ]]
```

in a POSIX shell

```sh
while [ "$i" -gt 0 ]
```

---

## Conclusion

While it may seem POSIX is rather harder to use, and it certainly may be at times, it gives you the power to move the script to any shell environment, i.e. portability. For example, you can run the same script on Windows in [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and in any [Linux shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_command-line_interpreters#Unix-like_systems).

I realize now, you specifically asked about the `if` conditional statements, and what I said is perfectly applicable to that question too.

Comment: I can't use SH, when the documentation I find on the internet is all about Bash, can you tell me which is the documentation page of shell script || SH

Comment: `man sh` should work on many platforms; maybe try also `man dash` etc. For the POSIX standard specifically, look at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html